# What is a strong verb that means to vulnerably (bravely) expose?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for an active verb that communicates the idea of taking great risk to share intimate desires of your heart for the sake of the greater good, love, connection, etc...

It must be positive, acknowledging that there is a hidden gift in perceived weakness. How, being vulnerable encourages others by normalizing their own fears, feelings of inadequacy and unmet desires.

Comment: @bof *Bare* is a weak verb because its past tense is just *bared*. But *bear* is a strong verb because it doesn't get a dental added to it in the past tense the way happens with weak verbs. Rather it changes its vowel like all strong verbs do, leaving you with *bore*.

Comment: Is say a strong verb? It changes its vowel *and* gets a dental added to it.

Comment: To @tchrist's point, an English "strong verb" is a verb that forms the past tense by changing the vowel of the present tense form; while a weak verb adds an "-ed". I think you don't mean that, but rather "a verb which connotes strength". Is that correct?

Comment: @bog "Say" is considered an [irregular weak verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_irregular_verbs#Weak_verbs), consisting of adding a dental also doing some type of contraction/shortening. Have/has and do/does are a couple other examples of this.

Comment: If you're not set on a verb, the expression "showing your belly" would be useful.

Comment: Wow, that is a tough question (because I can't think of an answer). Is your sentence sort of 'set in stone'? (Meaning you're just looking for a word to insert in a sentence whose structure you don't want to change?) If you or the rest of us can't come up with an appropriate verb, would a metaphor suit your purpose?

Comment: Hi, @Katie. I think you'll get better answers if you add a sentence showing how you want to use the word. Use a ___ or other placeholder where you want it to go. It can be the real sentence you're trying to write, or something else you make up that illustrates how this word could be used. This gives users a better idea of exactly what you want, and is also technically a requirement for this kind of question. If there are words that you've considered but rejected, tell us about those, too. Use the "edit" link just below your question to add details—basically, more info is better. Good luck!

Comment: We have a whole page of help with this sort of question. Unfortunately SE have changed things and it's no longer easy to find from the tag, but there's a link in the on-hold notice. Questions can be (and are) taken off hold, so I hope you'll be able to help the community give you an answer.